# How can I determine what namespaces are visible to a Python stack frame?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Consider the following code:

```
GLOBAL_VARIABLE = 1

def someFunction():
    nonLocalVariable = 2

    def anotherFunction():
        localVariable = 3

        class LocalClass(object):
            __metaclass__ = MyMetaClass
            __customCode = """
                    GLOBAL_VARIABLE + nonLocalVariable + localVariable
                """

    anotherFunction()

someFunction()
```

I'm the implementor of `MyMetaClass`, a meta-class that generates methods for
a class based on the contents of the `__customCode` property. `__customCode`
can include Python expressions, so I would like to be sure that a variable name
mentioned in `__customCode` refers to the same object as the same variable name
defined in a normal Python method would.

When the metaclass is invoked, it's handed a dict containing the contents of
the class, which means it knows about `__customCode`, but that's not much help.
If you use `inspect.currentframe(1)`, you get the stack-frame where the `class`
statement is executing, which is to say `anotherFunction()`. That stack-frame
has a `.f_locals` attribute (containing `localVariable`) and a `.f_globals`
attribute (containing `GLOBAL_VARIABLE`, amongst other things), but those two
together do not tell the whole story.

Given the stack-frame of `anotherFunction()` (or anything else I can grab hold
of from inside the implementation of `MyMetaClass`), how can I discover the
namespace where `nonLocalVariable` lives, and any other namespaces nested
between the global and local namespaces?

I'm currently using Python 2.7, but if the answer is different in Python 3.x,
that would be good to know too.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo: your edit was incorrect; the code was correctly nested, that is *the point* of this question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters cheers martijn, i tried to read the whole question to understand if he/she meant to indent it like that or was just a spacing error :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the `locals()` and `globals()` structure, the compiler adds information on 'free variables' in the form of cells pointing to locals in nested functions, for any *local* variable that is a) not being assigned to, and b) refers to a scoped variable (Python 3.x adds the `nonlocal` keyword to allow you to assign to such a variable too, just as with the `global` keyword).

In your specific case, there are *no* such variables. None of your nested code refers to `nonLocalVariable`; only if `anotherFunction` or `LocalClass` actually used that variable would the python compiler (so at byte compilation time) add the necessary structures to be able to pull out `nonLocalVariable` from the scope.

Here is an example nested setup:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     y = None
...     def bar():
...         return x
...     return bar
... 
>>> bar = foo('spam')
>>> foo.__code__.co_cellvars
('x',)
>>> bar.__code__.co_freevars
('x',)
>>> dir(bar.func_closure[0])
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'cell_contents']
>>> bar.func_closure[0].cell_contents
'spam'
```

Note how the `foo` codeobject lists `x` in the `co_cellvars` list, and the codeobject for `bar` has `x` listed in `co_freevars`; `y` is *not* listed in either because `bar` never uses it. The reference to the `bar` function has a `func_closure` structure, that holds the *current* value for `x` as given by the scope when `bar` was created. Code objects hold the bytecode for a function; they are created at compile time. The `func_closure` tuple is created at runtime based on the `freevars` and `cellvars` structures.

Because this happens at compile time, creating a reference to such a scoped variable dynamically is, at best, tricky. I would, for your own sake, not even bother to support using scoped variables in this case.

Comment: I knew the interpreter must have *some* information about enclosing namespaces, but I didn't realise it was done by the compiler. That kind of sucks, but Python seems to be generally hostile to this kind of meta-programming in general, so I'm not wholly surprised. This is just a corner-case, though, so I will do exactly as you suggest and ignore it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Screwtape: You can create a wrapper function with the scoped variables, and return the nested function; if it uses any of the scoped variables the resulting code object at least will have the right information. Then all you have to do is attach the correct scoping information (the `func_closure` info)... Fun! But you'd have to somehow force the compiler to list *any* and *all* locals in nested scopes to be available to cells. Not easy.